# What exactly is GCD and where should it be used?

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I think GCD is todo with asynchronous events, but specifically, I am not sure what type of events/where GCD comes in useful, apart from the obvious web requests.

Could you explain what GCD is and where it should/shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to read the chapter called "Dispatch Queues" in Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide. It is an excellent document and clearly depicts the differences with standard multi-thread programming. 
This reading (will not take you more than 10 minutes to read, quite more to digest of course!) is quite better than any other word I can put here!
[link to apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)