# What is the role of Grand Central Dispatch when implementing multitasking in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multitasking, grand-central-dispatch

I'm a little bit confusing those two concepts when it comes to multitasking implementation. I read that GCD effectively uses all device cores, and also facilitates the work of app developers by making  their apps multithreaded in a simpler way.

So the questions that arise to me are like, is GCD Apple preferred way for implementing multitasking? How does multitasking with GCD differs from multitasking without GCD?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539656/what-exactly-is-gcd-and-where-should-it-be-used

Comment: Are you really talking about "multitasking", i.e. running multiple applications at the same time/in the background? Or do you only mean "multithreading", i.e. doing work concurrently within the same app?

Comment: @nschum I mean doing the work concurrently within the same app.